# CSS files load but doesnt apply to my page codeignter 3

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter, i am still learning about it. My  problem it's that the css file is not applying on the page, it is linked, I can seet it but it doesnt work.
My header file.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Proyectos makers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/estilos.css'); ?>">
    
</head>
<body>
```

My css file:

```css
body{
    background-color: #CC00CC;
}
```

In my config/autoload.php I load the url helper

```html
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

I have yet  removed my index.php page in config.php

And this is my .htacces file:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

When i view the source code, the css file is linked. I clic on it and shows me the code of the css file. But doesn´t change the aspect of my site.

Comment: Hi, welcome! If you check your browser's console, do you see any errors? (such as an insecure request being blocked or something like that)

Comment: Hi, i see no errors. I have checked console and network and doesnt show me errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my error. It is not src, it is href in my link.
Bad:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/estilos.css'); ?>">
```

Good:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/estilos.css'); ?>">
```